# How to make a texture interact with scene lighting and shadows in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, transparency

I have a texture UV mapped on to an object (the logo decal), but it doesn't interact with lights or shadows as it should. How can I make it behave as it would naturally?

[image: cycles material nodes]

Comment: Try watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W07H7xeUnGE

Answer (score 9):

You do not need the *Transparent BSDF* node. Just plug the alpha from the image texture into the *Fac* of the *Mix* node.

The *Transparent BSDF* is a shader node, and the *Fac* on the *Mix* node is looking for a value 0 through 1, a black and white map.

Your logo will "interact with light", it just will not be glossy because of the way you are mixing the glossy nodes.

This is a simple node setup to mix the diffuse logo with a glossy node, yet still have the logo partially glossy.
Use the "white" end of the *ColorRamp* node to control how glossy the logo will be. White (a value of 1) will have no gloss, and black (a value of 0) will be full gloss, and you would not see the logo.
[image: cycles nodes]