# Background goes transparent when png UV map is applied

Tags: materials, uv

I have a png logo-label I want applied to a section of the display. Problem is when I set up the label material and apply it the background of the display goes transparent too.

[image]

Comment: look at your own question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40642/label-not-showing-up-as-transparent-or-showing-at-all

Comment: Think of it this way: the transparency controls what? Do you want to have the color of the object everywhere except where the texture is? Then use the alpha to mix the image and color. Do you want your object to be transparent except for the part where the texture is? Then use the alpha to control the transparent and diffuse shaders.

Comment: [My answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24225/2217) will help you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the alpha channel to control how the colors of the diffuse shader mix with your image. Use a RGB mix node.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I DID that once already. Here look. You can clearly see I had the alpha plugged into the color.  http://postimg.org/image/v9a0amzo5/

Comment: You don't need the trasnparent shader node, nor the mix shader node.

Comment: I unplug the mix shader. I unplug the transparent shader. I plug the alpha into the Color AND the Fac and STILL wrong http://postimg.org/image/ucvshqz5r/

Comment: see the picture... plug the image to the **bottom socket**. The bottom socket is foreground color, the one on top is the background color. You want your image to be "on top" of the background color.

Comment: Ok. except when tried that th color was completely wrong. http://postimg.org/image/641g5x03d/  Nevermind I wasted enough fo your time. I'll figure something else out -- I'll correct it in Photoshop.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: set the color on the mix rgb node: http://i.stack.imgur.com/72JKi.gif

Comment: But doing it THAT way does not allow the color to show THROUGH the transparent area --correct? What it's doing, in reality, is picking a color to make the transparent color the png same color of the display --Thereby completely defeating the idea of 'transparent' - at least the way I understand it.